# How can I include(load) more than one jsp files in spring mvc controller class?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

How can I include(load) more than one jsp files in spring mvc conroller class?

eg:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public void welcome() {

    include("file1.jsp");
    include("file2.jsp");
    include("file3.jsp");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At framework level, No you cannot do it. However, there is a hack you could try.

Create an array of name of pages you need to merge. Send it as a parameter to a dummy empty page.

The dummy page does this:

```
<c:forEach var="page" items="${pages}">
<c:import url="${page}"></c:import>    
</c:forEach>
```

This will iterate all the JSP files that you wish to show as a single view.

Hope this helps. Let me know if any further help is required.